# ValueError - "x_train_data" not shaped in three-dimensional

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, lstm

**Context:**
This step covers the preparation of the train data and the test data.

Codes:

**Min-Max Scaler**

```
scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))

data.index=data.Date
data.drop('Date',axis=1,inplace=True)

final_data = data.values
train_data=final_data[0:200,:]
valid_data=final_data[200:,:]

scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))

scaled_data=scaler.fit_transform(final_data)
x_train_data,y_train_data=[],[]
for i in range(60,len(train_data)):
    x_train_data.append(scaled_data[i-60:i,0])
    y_train_data.append(scaled_data[i,0])

x_train_data = np.array(x_train_data)
y_train_data = np.array(y_train_data)
```

**LSTM Model**

We are defining the Long Short-Term Memory model in this stage.

```
lstm_model=Sequential()
lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(np.shape(x_train_data)[1],1)))
lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=50))
lstm_model.add(Dense(1))
model_data=data[len(data)-len(valid_data)-60:].values
model_data=model_data.reshape(-1,1)
model_data=scaler.transform(model_data)
```

**Train and Test Data**

This stage comprises the preparation of both the train and test data.

```
lstm_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam')
lstm_model.fit(x_train_data,y_train_data,epochs=1,batch_size=1,verbose=2)

X_test=[]
for i in range(60,model_data.shape[0]):
    X_test.append(model_data[i-60:i,0])
X_test=np.array(X_test)
X_test=np.reshape(X_test,(X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],1))
```

**The error! :(**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-4bebe72cad71> in <module>()
      1 lstm_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam')
----> 2 lstm_model.fit(x_train_data,y_train_data,epochs=1,batch_size=1,verbose=2)
      3 
      4 X_test=[]
      5 for i in range(60,model_data.shape[0]):

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:830 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:813 run_step  *
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:770 train_step  *
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py:989 __call__  *
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py:212 assert_input_compatibility  *
        raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) + ' of layer ' +

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (1, 60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `x_train_data` needs to be 3 dimensional and in shape (number of observations, time steps, number of variables). So try:

```
 x_train_data = np.array(x_train_data)
 x_train_data = x_train_data.reshape(x_train_data.shape[0], x_train_data.shape[1], 1)
```

Same applies for `x_test_data`. You might need to apply `np.ravel(y_train_data)` before fitting. If other parts are ok then these changes should suffice

Comment: It threw an error in "x_train_data = x_train_data.reshape(x_train_data[0], x_train_data[1], 1)".

It says, "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index".

Comment: Sorry I made mistake. Now edited to the correct one, hopefully